# NetSuite Saved Search for Kit/Package - How to include columns for each component and their quantity

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to create a Saved Search for Kit/Package records. Each Kit/Package includes two component SKUs. The desired result is to have a Saved Search that pulls in each component SKU into its own column. I would also like another column for each of the respective quantities.

I am using this Saved Search to create an Advanced PDF/HTML template. So, I cannot use a Saved Search that includes summary fields. Also, these items cannot be grouped in the Saved Search because I need to reference them separately in the Advanced PDF/HTML template.

EXAMPLE: Kit/Package SKU "XYZXYZ" includes 10 x "Component 1" and 1 x "Component 2". The Saved Search would include the following columns:

- Kit/Package SKU
- Component 1 SKU
- Component 1 QTY
- Component 2 SKU
- Component 2 QTY

How can I accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not a feature supported by NetSuite. There is an enhancement request submitted for this feature.

Comment: still not a feature in NetSuite or feature added?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done.  Follow the steps below:

1) Create an Item saved search.

2) Use the following settings

- Criteria: Type is Kit/Package
- Result: Name
- Result: Member Item (Or whatever you're using for SKU.  Maybe Member Item Fields...Internal ID)
- Result: Member Quantity
- Available Filter: Name. Show in Filter : Yes

Save & Run

3) Create the Advanced HTML template. Use this code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE pdf PUBLIC "-//big.faceless.org//report" "report-1.1.dtd">
<pdf>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<#list results as result>
<#if result_index==0>
Kit/Package SKU ${result.itemid} includes ${result.memberquantity} x ${result.memberitem}</#if>
<#if result_index==1> and ${result.memberquantity} x ${result.memberitem}
</#if>
</#list>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</pdf>
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be a step in the right direction but it still has some errors.The Saved Search has 21 lines, but the print template generated 21 pages of the same two SKUs. Also, the Kit/Package combination it printed is incorrect. It used two component SKUs from two different Kits. It may help to mention that not all Kits have two components. Kits can have either one or two components. Is there another solution?

Comment: This solution won't work for printing multiple pages of components simultaneously.  That's what the filter is for.  Filter down to a single Kit/Package, then print.  If you want to print multiple pages of components you'll have to change the logic in the template. Right now it's hard-coded to print the 1st and 2nd lines of the saved search, regardless of how many lines are in the saved search.